# iCarousel numberOfItemsInCarousel

Tags: ios, swift, carousel

I use iCarousel module into my CollectionView. The Carousel View is in my UICollectionViewCell.

My code is as following.

```
class CelebrityDetailHeaderCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate, SDCycleScrollViewDelegate, iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var backgroudLab: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name_en: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name_tw: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var intro: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var DetailImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var iCarouselView: iCarousel!

let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    iCarouselView.delegate = self
    iCarouselView.dataSource = self

    iCarouselView.type = .Linear
}

func numberOfItemsInCarousel(carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let tempView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: screenWidth/2, width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth/2))
    tempView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return tempView
}
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, valueForOption option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    if option == iCarouselOption.Spacing {
        return 1.2
    }
    return value
}
```

}

The error message is as following

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSObject numberOfItemsInCarousel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f99bb3734a0'

I have set numberOfItemsInCarousel why the error message showed this. Does anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Because somewhere it's "NSObject" object that receive the instruction to call `numberOfItemsInCarousel:`, but not a `CelebrityDetailVC` object.

Comment: How to add iCarousel into collectionviewcell?

Answer (score 0):

Look you need to add a dealloc method in your cell. As your cell is getting deallocated and the iCarousel delegate is calling that method to some deallocated instance thats why it is crashing

write a dealloc method like this

```
- (void)dealloc{
    iCarouselView.delegate = nil
    iCarouselView.dataSource = nil
 }
```